# Uber Login Error

Tags: uber-api

We have integrated Uber in our android app. Once OAuth is completed, user will be redirected to a web view. Recently in few cases, user is redirected to an error screen (user is entering correct credentials ). Can you direct us to a correct documentation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can start with [Android](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android) documentation. You can also check out Git repository for [rides-android-sdk](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk). And finally [best practices](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices) from Uber documentation. 
Some tips on your troubleshooting:

- Make sure you are following proper Oauth2 authentication flow
- Check your redirect URL on the application dashboard - and use this URL in your auth process.
- Check your scopes - make sure you have a scope selected for required API request.

If you want any further help please specify more info about your app, what you are trying to achieve- what calls are you making, share your authentication flow, and error logs if you have it.